# React Router with Node JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

When using React-Router, you only serve up the original index.html with Node because the client handles the rest. I understand how to route between different pages once the user is at the home page. However, let's say the user types in the URL '/about'. Node will serve up the index.html, but how do you tell React-Router to then immediately take the user to the about page? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your BUILT create-react-app project sitting inside you node/public folder.  you need to let express know that the index.html file will be handling the routes.  see super simple server example below.  this will use react routers setup properly.

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html')));

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thank you! That gave me everything I needed to solve this )